# How are Rust's Arc and Rc types different from having garbage collection?

Tags: pointers, garbage-collection, rust

[*The Rust Programming Language*, first edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/README.html) says that Rust does not have a garbage collector:

> It maintains these goals without having a garbage collector

However, in [discussing choosing your guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/choosing-your-guarantees.html#rct) it also says:

> `Rc<T>` is a reference counted pointer. In other words, this lets us have multiple "owning" pointers to the same data, and the data will be dropped (destructors will be run) when all pointers are out of scope.

As far as I understand, this is exactly how pointers work in a garbage-collected language like Python.

I consider garbage collection to be any process which prevents the need for manual deallocation of dynamically-allocated memory. I think I don't understand what the Rust guide considers to be garbage collection however.

Comment: Your definition conflates "garbage collection" per se with "automatic memory management."  Automatic memory management could refer to any number of approaches for non-manual memory management.  Garbage collection is one such approach:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's never really been a consensus on whether refcounting counts as a form of garbage collection.  And even if it is, it's so different than other forms that the comparison isn't useful. If you consider optional RAII-powered reference counting smart pointers in the standard library as Rust being garbage collected, then C++ is garbage collected too.

Comment: This is how pointers work in Python in *most cases*. In addition to reference counting, Python has a fall-back GC for reference cycles. More about reference cycles: [Geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-python/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I consider garbage collection to be any process which prevents the need for manual deallocation of dynamically-allocated memory

Then Rust does have "garbage collection"!

```
fn make_stuff() {
    // Allocate memory on the heap and store `true` in it
    let thing = Box::new(true);
    // Allocate memory on the heap and store 1000 numbers in it.
    let things = vec![42; 1000];
} // Look Ma! No manual deallocation!
```

When `thing` and `things` go out of scope (in this case, at the end of the method), then the memory they had allocated will be freed for you.

`Rc` and `Arc` allow more flexibility than this; you should give [their docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) a read to know more.

---

In addition to @Manishearth's answer, there's also this detail (emphasis mine):

> automatically freed at the end of its **last owner's lifetime**

In many garbage-collected languages, garbage collection happens out-of-band with the rest of your code. In Rust, the location of deallocation will be known.

Given this Java:

```
public static ArrayList alpha()
{
    return new ArrayList();
}

public static void beta()
{
    alpha(); // Unused result
}
```

I do not believe that you can say *with certainty* when the ArrayList will be removed from memory. In the equivalent Rust code, you know that an `Arc` or `Rc` will be destructed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 11):

[This](https://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/06/02/removing-garbage-collection-from-the-rust-language/) article is a bit old, regarding how Rust has changed now, but it highlights what it means that Rust does not have GC. Only RAII and ownership are intrinsic to Rust. They helps writing reference-counting alike GCs such as Rc and Arc, but those are not part of the language, they're part of the standard library. And it makes a huge difference.

If you consider writing an operating system in Rust, you can't use any form of GC in part of your code or use the standard library. At this level, it's important to know what is part of the language and what is not. For a simple example, have look [here](https://github.com/charliesome/rustboot).

In contrast, in a language such as Java or Python, you can't prevent your code from using the GC as it use it implicitly by design of the language.

In Rust, like in [C/C++](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) a GC is part from a library and it's use is explicit.

Answer (score 7):

`Rc` has no cycle collection. If you create a cycle of references, you will probably crash the program as it tries to increment the refcount.

Though this technically counts as a garbage collector too, it's not a universally useful one since you have the restriction on the types it can contain.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "you have the restriction on the types it can contain"?

Comment: @MikeVella I can't have cyclic references. There's no in built restriction, but it's one you should follow.

Comment: It is my understanding that [reference counting is *a* form of garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), so the fact that `Rc`/`Arc` do not handle cycles does not **automatically** disqualify it as a garbage collector.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, and I mentioned that in the answer, however when people ask if Rust has a GC they mean a cycle collecting GC. It's misleading, and hence we just say that Rust doesn't have a GC. A refcounting GC is easy to implement out of tree as well, so it's low cost (and you can thus say that all object oriented language with pointers have refcounting GCs), however a good cycle collecting GC usually needs integration with the runtime and all and is nontrivial to implement -- when people ask for a GC, that's what they're asking for.

Comment: Actually, I believe you are prevented from creating cycles at compile time.  Which is way better than crashing the program (or, in my opinion, leaking memory).

Comment: @DavidRoundy no, you can create cycles using `Rc` and `RefCell`.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on being correct, a garbage collector collects. It collects a list of memory locations to free. Rc/Arc on the other hand does not, so I don't think you can call it garbage collection.

However rust has the `std::gc` module, so yea rust has in fact an optional garbage collector for now.

Comment: `std::gc` was [removed](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-October/011267.html) between the 0.11 and 0.12 release.

Comment: And IIRC, `Gc` was never implemented properly, it was just `Rc` in disguise